# Reading specified line using Perl program and command-line arguments

Tags: linux, perl

So, let's say I am writing a Perl program:

```
./program.perl 10000 < file
```

I want it to read the 10000th line of "file" only. How could I do it using input redirection in this form? It seems that I keep getting something along the lines of 10000 is not a file.

I thought this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$line_num = 0;
while ( defined ($line = <>) && $line_num < $ARGV[0]) {
    ++$line_no;
    if ($line_no == $ARGV[0]) {
        print "$line\n";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

But it failed miserably.

Comment: Please `use strict`, as it would have caught your typo (`$line_num` vs. `$line_no`).  Please also _show us the error messages_, as perl's complaint that it *"Can't open 10000: No such file or directory..."* is a good clue as to what else has gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are command-line arguments, then `<>` opens the so-named files and reads from them, and if not, then it takes from standard-input. (See ["I/O Operators" in the perlop man-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).)

If, as in your case, you want to read from standard-input whether or not there are command-line arguments, then you need to use `<STDIN>` instead:

```
while ( defined ($line = <STDIN>) && $line_num < $ARGV[0]) {
```

Comment: @JordanCarney: You're welcome! By the way, I should also have mentioned -- you don't need to create your own `$line_num` variable; there's a predefined `$.` that does exactly this. (See [the `perlvar` man-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile)

```
use Tie::File;
my ($name, $num) = @ARGV;
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $name or die $!;

print $file[$num];
untie @file;
```

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl file.csv 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. == 10000; exit if $. > 10000'
```

`$.` counts lines read from `stdin`. `-n` implicitly wraps program in:

```
while (<>) {
   ...program...
}
```

Comment: `print and exit if $. == 10_000`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this very simply using awk:

```
awk 'NR==10000' < file
```

or sed:

```
sed -n '10000p' file
```